# 2 dimensional table in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

We're evaluating Ember.js (against Angular) for a complex app by building a few "toy apps".  One of them is to present data in a table.

I've been through countless SO postings, the Ember Website, and other sites but can't quite find the key to making it work.  The closest examples were at [xeqtit](http://www.xeqtit.com/blog/2012/05/creating-a-stock-ticker-table-using-ember-js-take-ii#.UNM4txzlV8M) and this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7MAp/).

Quite stuck.

Any pointers to how to set this up?  Been reading web postings for days just don't see the answer out there...

## The Problem Statement

To simplify the problem: imagine a list of routers, each router can have a variable number of interfaces, those interfaces have an address, status, etc.

The final table would look like:

```
__________________________________________________
Machine       |  Interfaces
rt1.rp.ps.com | UP | UP | UP | NG | UP | UP | NG |
rt2.rp.ps.com | UP | UP |                        |
rt3.rp.ps.com | UP | UP | UP |                   |
rt4.rp.ps.com | UP | UP | UP | NG | UP | UP | NG |
rt5.rp.ps.com | UP | UP | UP | NG |              |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Note the variable number of columns.

## The Objects:

```
App.Machine = Ember.Object.extend(
{
    nickname: '',
    address: '',
    ifaces: []
});

App.Interface = Ember.Object.extend(
{
    num: '',
    status: '',
    address: ''
});
```

## The Markup

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="machinelist">
        <p>List of Machines</p>
        <table>
            {{#each App.MachinelistController }}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{nickname}}</td>
                    <td>{{address}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            {{#each p in App.MachinelistController.getInterfaces}}
                            <tr><td>{{p}}</td></tr>
                            {{/each}}
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </table>
    </script>
```

## The Controller

The Controller first reads a database to get a list of machines and their addresses.  It then queries each machine to fetch the list of interfaces.  [I've simplified the code to show the core of the issue ... excuse any typos]

```
App.MachinelistController = Ember.ArrayController.create(
{
    content: [],
    getInterfaces: function(x, y, z)
    {
        // This didn't work
        return this.getPath('interfaces.status');
    }.property('@each.read'),
    polling: false,
    machinePollTime: 5000,
    detailPollTime: 3000,
```

The list of machines is retrieved from a database via PHP.  It populates the 'content' of the Controller with Machine objects, but no details on the interfaces are filled in yet:
        fetch:  function()
        {
            console.log('machine fetch');
            var self = this;

```
        $.get("be/getDVStorList.php", function(data, textStatus)
        {
            self.set('content', []);
            var statusReport = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            statusReport.machineList.forEach(function(v)
            {
                var machine = App.Machine.create(
                    {
                        nickname: v['machineName'],
                        address: v['machineIpAddr']
                    });
                self.pushObject( machine );
            })
        });
        if (self.polling)
            setTimeout( function() { self.fetch(); }, self.machinePollTime);
        return this;
    },
```

In a separate polling loop (still in the ArrayController), each machine in the content list is polled to get the info about its interfaces:

```
    fetchDetails: function ()
    {
        console.log("fetch details");
        var self = this;
        self.forEach(function(item, index, self)
        {
            console.log(item.get('address'));
            var addr = item.get('address');
            var base = "http://"+ addr; 
            var slug = "/cgi-bin/DvStorGetStatus.cgi?Recording=1&Playback=1&Structured=1";
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: base+slug,
                timeout: 10000,
                cache: false,
                success: buildMachineCallback(addr),
            });
        });

        if (self.polling)
            setTimeout( function () { self.fetchDetails(); }, self.detailPollTime);
        return true;

        function buildMachineCallback(addr)
        {
            return function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { updateDetailsCallback(data, textStatus, jqXHR, addr); };
        };
```

This function is called when the poll to each machine returns.  It adds the 'interfaces' into the data structure:

```
        // Update *data structure* based on return values in XML
        function updateDetailsCallback(data, textStatus, jqXHR, addr)
        {
            // might be more than one with this address
            var theMachines = self.filterProperty('address')

            var interfaceList = $(data).find('Interface');
            var interfaces = [];
            $(playInterfaceerList).each(function()
            {
                var anInterface = App.Interface.create();
                var num = $(this).find('InterfaceNum').text();
                anInterface.set('num',  num);
                anInterface.set('status',  $(this).find('InterfaceStatus').text());

                interfaces[num-1] = anInterface;
            })

            // update all machines sharing this IP address
            theMachines.forEach(function (m, idx, tm)
            {
                tm[idx].set('alias', $(data).find('Generic').find('Alias').text());
                tm[idx].set('health', $(data).find('Generic').find('SystemHealth').text());

                interfaces.forEach(function(p)
                {
                    tm[idx].get('ifaces').pushObject( App.Interface.create(p) );
                })
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: There is a table implementation based on Ember.js, I don't have dig into it for now, but perhaps it's a hint for you: http://addepar.github.com/ember-table/

Comment: You don't need either framework. A function which takes an empty table as an input and builds itself using [higher order array functions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/08/19/10442582.aspx) would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions that should works.

- Ember-table, an Ember plugin: http://addepar.github.io/#/ember-table/overview
- jQuery-datatable, a jQuery plugin: https://datatables.net/

Using the jQuery plugin will be more complicated because it is not directly linked to the ember render process.